# How can I go to Inbox Tab when I clicked on the notification regardless of where I am in the app?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to go to "inbox" tab when I clicked on the notification.

This is the notificationManager:

```
func didReceiveNotification(notif: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    print("notification... \(notif)")

    guard let msgData = notif["gcm.notification.messageData"] as? String else {

        return
    }

    print("msgData: \(msgData)")
    CommandManager.shared.processNotification(msgData)
}
```

This is the commandManager:

```
func processNotification(_ commands: String) {

    var dict:[String:Any] = [:]

    dict = dict.convertToDictionary(text: commands) ?? [:]

    print("dict \(dict)")
    sendMessageToFirestore(data: dict)

    let inbox = EngageViewController()
    //present the inbox tab
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by tab ? tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rootViewController`

```
func processNotification(_ commands: String) {

    var dict:[String:Any] = [:]

    dict = dict.convertToDictionary(text: commands) ?? [:]

    print("dict \(dict)")
    sendMessageToFirestore(data: dict)

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "inboxPage") as! UIViewController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
}
```

## Edit

If it's a UITabBarController, use:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
viewcontroller.selectedIndex = 1 //index of your inbox
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Answer (score 0):

If the initial view of app is TabBarController then you can do something like in

> AppDelegate.swift

```
guard let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
        return
    }
```

so,

`tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1` `//Whatever the index of inbox is`